# Unable to receive email during AWS Cognito signup phase

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

After have client_id and client_secret properly imported into my code and have the hash secret generated using the credential and username, this is what i have for sign up:

```
user_attributes = [{"Name": "email", "Value": email}]
cognito_client.sign_up(
        ClientId=_CLIENT_ID,
        SecretHash=secret_hash,
        Username=username,
        UserAttributes=user_attributes,
        Password=password,
    )
```

I tried to trigger this `sign_up()` method using a Lambda function, and this is what I get in the terminal every time when I wanted to create a new user

```
on 'AuthFunction' timed out after 10 seconds                                                                                                                            
"errorMessage": "An error occurred (CodeDeliveryFailureException) when calling the SignUp operation: Unable to deliver message".
```

I checked my userpool in AWS Cognito console, and I can see a user created but with the email field left unverified. The email I used here has been verified on SES (I am currently in the sandbox mode)

Anyone ran into this issue before?

UPDATE:
I might have to contact AWS support for the issue described in this thread because it looks like this very Userpool I created also has other weird problems: 1. I can't update REPLY-TO email config (originally left blank) under the Messaging tab 2. I can't deactivate Deletion Protection, which in turn prevents me from deleting the Userpool as a whole. The error message I received after implementing any of the actions listed above is `code: InvalidParameterException message: Unable to deliver message`. So what I did was I created a new Userpool with a valid REPLY-TO email (updated the corresponding credentials), and I received an automated email with verification code.